# Java, Output not being displayed?

Tags: java, swing, loops, output

The task was to display the users full name, a random even number and initials.

For example. Joshua Ethan Paul Smith

SmithJEPS320

When I press my get code button nothing happens, why is this?

```
package pack;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.math.*;



public class saf extends javax.swing.JFrame {



    public saf() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        btnfullname = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txaDisplay = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        TxaDisplay = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        btnrandomGenerator = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnCode = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnfullname.setText("Enter");
        btnfullname.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnfullnameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        TxaDisplay.setEditable(false);
        TxaDisplay.setColumns(20);
        TxaDisplay.setRows(5);
        txaDisplay.setViewportView(TxaDisplay);

        btnrandomGenerator.setText("Generate Random Number");
        btnrandomGenerator.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnrandomGeneratorActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnCode.setText("Get Code!");
        btnCode.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnCodeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(54, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(txaDisplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 353, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(40, 40, 40))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnrandomGenerator)
                        .addGap(112, 112, 112))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnCode)
                        .addGap(165, 165, 165))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnfullname)
                        .addGap(177, 177, 177))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(btnfullname)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(txaDisplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 142, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(btnrandomGenerator)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnCode)
                .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnfullnameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    String fullname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your full name:");

    TxaDisplay.append(fullname);
    }                                           

    private void btnrandomGeneratorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    int randnum; //Code for a 3 digit even number
    do
    {
       randnum=(int)(Math.random()*900)+100; 
    }
    while(randnum%2!=0);
    TxaDisplay.append("" + randnum);
    }                                                  

    private void btnCodeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    int randnum = 0 ;
    String fullname = "" ;
    String initials ="";
    int posSpc = fullname.lastIndexOf(" ");
    String surname = fullname.substring(posSpc+1, fullname.length());
    initials = initials + fullname.charAt(0);
    for(int i =0; i< fullname.length() ; i++)
    {
        char ch=fullname.charAt(i);
            if(ch==' ')
            {
                initials = initials + fullname.charAt(i+1);

            }
    }
    String code = surname + initials + "" + randnum;
    TxaDisplay.append(fullname+"\n");
    TxaDisplay.append(code);

    }                                       

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(saf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(saf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(saf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(saf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new saf().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextArea TxaDisplay;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnCode;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnfullname;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnrandomGenerator;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane txaDisplay;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Did you try with setText instead of append?

Comment: Yes, but they had no effect on the output of the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather easy. You initiate fullname to the empty string and then try to access the first character of the empty `String` --> `StringIndexOutOfBoundException`:

```
int randnum = 0 ;
String fullname = "" ;// Here empty string !!!
String initials ="";
int posSpc = fullname.lastIndexOf(" "); // this is always -1
String surname = fullname.substring(posSpc+1, fullname.length()); // This is the empty string
initials = initials + fullname.charAt(0); // That throws a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

If you want this to work, you need to:

1. Make a private variable: `private String fullname`
2. Get rid of all local variables `fullname` and access the private variable of your class instead
3. In the `btnCodeActionPerformed`, check that `fullname` is not empty
4. Possibly disable the Get code button as long as fullname is empty

Something like this (not tested):

```
public class saf extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private String fullname;


    public saf() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        btnfullname = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txaDisplay = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        TxaDisplay = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        btnrandomGenerator = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnCode = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnfullname.setText("Enter");
        btnfullname.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnfullnameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        TxaDisplay.setEditable(false);
        TxaDisplay.setColumns(20);
        TxaDisplay.setRows(5);
        txaDisplay.setViewportView(TxaDisplay);

        btnrandomGenerator.setText("Generate Random Number");
        btnrandomGenerator.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnrandomGeneratorActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnCode.setText("Get Code!");
        btnCode.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnCodeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(54, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(txaDisplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 353, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(40, 40, 40))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnrandomGenerator)
                        .addGap(112, 112, 112))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnCode)
                        .addGap(165, 165, 165))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnfullname)
                        .addGap(177, 177, 177))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(btnfullname)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(txaDisplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 142, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(btnrandomGenerator)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnCode)
                .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnfullnameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    fullname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your full name:");

    TxaDisplay.append(fullname);
    }                                           

    private void btnrandomGeneratorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    int randnum; //Code for a 3 digit even number
    do
    {
       randnum=(int)(Math.random()*900)+100; 
    }
    while(randnum%2!=0);
    TxaDisplay.append("" + randnum);
    }                                                  

    private void btnCodeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                        
    if(fullname==null||fullname.trim().isEmpty()) {
          return;
    }
    int randnum = 0 ;
    String initials =;
    int posSpc = fullname.lastIndexOf(" ");
    String surname = fullname.substring(posSpc+1, fullname.length());
    initials = fullname.charAt(0);
    for(int i =0; i< fullname.length() ; i++)
    {
        char ch=fullname.charAt(i);
            if(ch==' ')
            {
                initials = initials + fullname.charAt(i+1);

            }
    }
    String code = surname + initials + "" + randnum;
    TxaDisplay.append(fullname+"\n");
    TxaDisplay.append(code);

    }                                       

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(saf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(saf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(saf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(saf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new saf().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextArea TxaDisplay;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnCode;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnfullname;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnrandomGenerator;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane txaDisplay;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: @rubin.kazan post your edited code to see what's wrong. Do this by editing your original post.

Comment: Sorry about this, I am using Netbeans and am unsure how I can add this code in as I am disregarding the GUI I have created using the actual design tab. I'm not sure where this code needs to be placed exactly as netbeans does not allow me to Copy and paste it in some areas

Comment: @rubin.kazan If Netbeans does not let you do that, I guess that a good old notepad shouldn't cause any problem. Just open the java file in notepad, copy/paste the code, save it. Then refresh the class in NetBeans and run it.